# Visual Studio 2015 Web Test with Data from Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2015, webtest

I'm writing a webtest in Visual Studio 2015. The webtest I currently have allows me to run a static test.
I would like to spice things up and therefore add more realistic data. The data I want to use is stored in an Oracle Database 12c.
So I'm trying to add a new Data Source to the webtest. I enter the TNSName, Username and Password for which I would like to connect and test the connection. The connection can be established, but the list with tables I can choose from is empty.

Connecting to the same Database using the "Server Explorer" in Visual Studio 2015 works. And using this method I do get the full list of Tables contained in that Database. I can even query any of the tables.

So how can I fix my webtest to have access to a specific database table (row)?

Answer (score 3):

If you can connect to the DB but you don't see the needed tables it should be a permission issue.

Do you use same credentials from "VS->Server Explorer" to connect to the DB?

If this is not the case, do you have more than one Oracle clients installed in your system? If yes, then most probably, the DataSource control uses the wrong client and  the "Server Explorer" the correct one.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is not a permission issue. This is because I connect with the same credentials to the same database using two different "VS-Tool". While the "Server Explorer" shows all tables and table content, the WebTest DataSource does not allow my to select data from any of the tables.

Comment: Plus there is only 1 oracle client installed

Answer (score 1):

Are you using synonyms as proxies for your tables (e.g. for permission reasons)? synonyms will not show up when querying the list of tables that the user can access. They need be queried separately. When only the available tables are queried but not the vendor specific aliases this might lead to an empty list.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install `ODAC` for `Visual Studio 2015` to view the database tables. Here is the link for it.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odacmsidownload-2745497.html